# MySql Column Matching with 3 contiguous numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have two tables, let's say called AllComputers and MfgComputers.  The interesting columns in Allcomputers are Brand_Name, Model_Name and Model_Number.  The interesting column in Mfgcomputers is Product_Name.

I can use the following query to display all of the rows that have a Brand_Name of HP and Model_Name OR Model_Number that exactly match Product_Name.

```
select * from AllComputers,MfgComputers where AllComputers.Brand_Name='HP' AND AllComputers.Model_Number=MfgComputers.Product_Name OR AllComputers.Model_Name=MfgComputers.Product_Name;
```

I would like to match where the Brand_Name is HP but use LIKE or REGEX to match all rows were the Model_Number and Model_Name match Product_Name only when at least three contiguous numbers are contained in both that match.

So if I have  Model_Name as HP Pavilion 500 All-in-One PC and Product_Name as HP 500 All-in-One PC, I would like to return only the matches where both have 500 as opposed to all that contain "All-in-One PC.

I tried subbing out the last two = signs in the above query with LIKE but that still matched only exact matches since I didn't know how to put in a wild card for an entire column.

I know I can use wildcards if just matching against one specific model such as:
    select * from AllComputers where Model_Number LIKE '%500%';
or
    select * from AllComputers where Model_Number REGEXP '500';

However, I am wondering if it is possible to do that between the columns for all model matches that have at least 3 contiguous numbers.

Answer (score 0):

REGEXP in MySQL has wildcards for numerics, so try `REGEXP '.*[0-9][0-9][0-9].*'`

.* is the equivalent of LIKE '%', so that's sandwiching 3 numerics digits between two %s, in effect.

Answer (score 0):

This will bring back the models which are having at least three continuous digits.

```
where Model_Number REGEXP '[0-9]{3}'
```

Updated based on your comment:

```
select * from 
  AllComputers, MfgComputers
where
  AllComputers.Brand_Name='HP' AND
  AllComputers.Model_Number REGEXP '[0-9]{3}' -- missing AND/OR here
  MfgComputers.Product_Name OR  -- make sure you are grouping using () for this OR
  AllComputers.Model_Name REGEXP '[0-9]{3}' -- missing AND/OR here
  MfgComputers.Product_Name;
```

Comment: I have used REGEXP for queries on a single table but how do I use this for matching between two tables.  I tried this but got a syntax error.    select * from AllComputers,MfgComputers where AllComputers.Brand_Name='HP' AND AllComputers.Model_Number REGEXP '[0-9]{3}' MfgComputers.Product_Name OR AllComputers.Model_Name REGEXP '[0-9]{3}' MfgComputers.Product_Name;

Comment: Where you mention I am missing AND/OR is where I previously had =.  I am just unsure how to keep the equals to match the columns but incorporate the regex as well that is completed before the matching takes place.

Comment: For simplicity, here consider `REGEXP` as `=`. Which means think as `model_number = '[0-9]{3}'` and then place your `AND/OR`